# Finding the 3D coordinates of an unknown point from three known points

Tags: geometry

> How can I find the coordinates $(x,y,z)$ in a $3d$ space when,

A) the unknown point is $(x,y,z)$;

B) there are three known points viz. $(a1,b1,c1)$, $(a2,b2,c2)$ and $(a3,b3,c3)$;

C) the distances from the three known points are $D1$, $D2$, $D3$, respectively.

Comment: You can't generally determine this with three points.  1 Sphere intersected with 1 Sphere results in null, 1 point, or a circle. That intersection with another sphere can be null, 1 point, 2 points or a circle.  In non-degenerate cases, you need 4 points.

Answer (score 1):

It would involve solving a system of 3 equations with 3 unknowns, where the solution $(x,y,z)$ represents the intersection point of the following three 3D spheres:
$$
(x-a_1)^2 + (y-b_1)^2 + (z-c_1)^2 = (D_1)^2\\
(x-a_2)^2 + (y-b_2)^2 + (z-c_2)^2 = (D_2)^2\\
(x-a_3)^2 + (y-b_3)^2 + (z-c_3)^2 = (D_3)^2
$$

Comment: Thanks Adriano. Could you please let me know the algebraic solutions for x, y and z for the above? For example: x = sqrt (....) etc

Comment: @SubhenduSeth Have you solved the equations yourself and are just looking for a simpler form?

Comment: @MarkPing No, I could not solve the equations. Any help will be welcome.